# Javascript is not running in the externall file

Tags: javascript, gulp-sass, gulp-concat

I am using GULP and everything works fine on the first page. I linked another `project_1.html`  page to it but for some reasons its JavaScript is not working. External html file recognizes Sass except for new linked `scrit2.js` file. Any idea what may cause it?  Here is Gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
gutil = require('gulp-util'), 
concat = require('gulp-concat'), 
compass = require('gulp-compass'), 
connect = require('gulp-connect');  


var jsSources = [
'1_components/scripts/*.js'
];

var sassSources = [
    '1_components/sass/*.scss'
];

var htmlSources = [
    '2_builds/development/*html'
];
gulp.task('js', function(){
    gulp.src(jsSources)
    .pipe(concat('script.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('2_builds/development/js'))
    .pipe(connect.reload())
});
```

in the second HTML I included

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

The same what I have on the main page

Here is an image of my workflow 
http://s8.postimg.org/dytbyze4l/111.png

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not clear to me.

Your index.html includes the script.js from development/js/.
Your project_1.html includes the script2.js? Is that correct?

If so, ensure that script2.js is inside your development/js/ folder. I only see the script.js being created inside your gulp script. Is your script2.js really being deployed into your build folder?

Comment: check an image link pls

Comment: jsSources includes all js files. Of course script2 is with script in the same folder. I believe link to the image will show

Comment: And you did check your concat-file for the contents of your script2.js?

Comment: I even did this  .pipe(concat('script.js', 'script2.js'))  nothing works